# Can I use this op amp to scale 0-3.3V to 0-5v?

Tags: 741-opamp

I recently came in to a voltage meter 0-5v. I want to use it with esp8266 as a humidity display for my weather information station.

the exp8266 model I'm using (wemos/nodMCU) is 3.3V, I can use PWM to set the needle, but it won't use the full range of the meter. I need to scale the voltage up to 0-5v.

[image]

So, after reading a bit I decide what I need is an op amp. I order one that seemed like it would work from the data sheet... but I don't really know how to set it up.

[image]

https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/tlv2462.pdf

Here is how I've hooked it up.

[image]

Comment: It won't work like this. Your amplifier circuit needs a bit more components (2 resistors at least). What you need is a non-inverting amplifier with ratio 5/3,3. You will also be limited because the op amp is limited to max 4,9V in output when supplied with 5V.

Comment: 4.9 will be good enough. I can adjust the scale to match it. 
where can I find out about where I need to put those other components?  I'd also like to know WHY I need them so I can learn to do this myself.

Comment: Why have you placed a tag called "741-opamp"?

Comment: I just placed the general op amp tag... that might be a mistake..

Answer (score 4):

- meters of this size are around 1mA full-scale meaning 1k Ohm/volt.
  This is class 2.5 or 2.5% accuracy shown in the fine print.

A primitive yet simple and elegant solution is to change the internal resistance to 66% of the total value of resistance that is full-scale current with a 1%  resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCEVQ1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Disassemble measure required current for full scale @ 3.3V  and add to R2 as shown then reassemble in reverse.

Comment: +1 Neatsy tricksy :-)

Comment: I had a million of them....

Comment: Meters or ideas?

Comment: # of Neatsy tricksy problems

Comment: If my former employer got 1 contract we would have wireless ISM band 2 way meters sharing 1 RF channel for a million energy meter retrofits

Comment: I need to learn the anatomy of the meter... this should be fun.

Comment: They add diodes to current limit the meter current rated often for 50 ~100uA or 0.2V

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq22FA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R3 & C1 form a low-pass filter with cutoff f = 1/2piRC ~= 1.6Hz. Ceramic X7R is okay for this part.

R1 and R2 set the gain, and are chosen so that R2/(R1+R2) ~= 3.3V/5.0V, are
high enough not to significantly load OA1 output, and are standard E96 1% values.

If you replace R1 with R4+RV1 you can trim the output sensitivity.

I suggest using somewhat less than the 5V angle (maybe 90-95%) and trimming the full scale
in with the  pot if you go this way.

OA1 should also have 100nF bypass capacitor across the power supply pins near the chip (not shown).

Comment: This may reach 4.7V

Comment: Adding an output pullup resistor may help in some cases. (Not strictly 'by the book' but can be useful).

Comment: I did this and it only got up to 4.7V. That's better though.